# Toggle this element on material table cell angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-ng-if, angular-material-table

I'm trying to change a style and increment a favorites count, the problem is my code changes the style for all heart elements. I've tried using index like `favClicked === i` but then when you click on another heart, it disables the style from the previous click.

My code:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; let i = index" class="favorite">
          <mat-icon
            (click)="showRed = true; increment(showRed)"
            *ngIf="!showRed"
            >favorite</mat-icon
          >
          <mat-icon
            (click)="showRed = false; increment(showRed)"
            class="red"
            *ngIf="showRed"
            >favorite</mat-icon
          >
        </td>
```

...

```
increment(showRed: boolean) {
    console.log(showRed);
    if (showRed) {
      this.childComponent.incrementCount();
    } else {
      this.childComponent.decrementCount();
    }
  }
```

Screenshot of the problem; you can see it changes the styling for all the hearts on click of the top heart, which originally was black color and changes to red on click.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used `item.clicked` which uses the item iteration, which targeted the table cell click of the heart. Then I reverse the boolean on click `item.clicked = !item.clicked;`, use `[ngClass]="{ red: item.clicked }"` to select the red class if true. Then increment in the method.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; let i = index" class="favorite">
   <mat-icon (click)="item.clicked = !item.clicked; increment(item.clicked, item, i)"
   ngClass]="{ red: item.clicked }">favorite</mat-icon>
</td>
```

...

```
 increment(item: boolean) {
    if (item) {
      this.childComponent.incrementCount();
    } else {
      this.childComponent.decrementCount();
    }
  }
```